# Processing a list within Python module works, but processing same list in a separate file does not

Tags: python, io

I'm trying to process a list contained within a separate text file. I am able to read the file, and generate an output containing the contents of the file, but the output generated is the unprocessed version, identical to the input. 
I do not encounter this problem when the list is contained within the module that I'm working with - the process runs successfully. Any ideas why using the input file is causing problems?

This runs successfully (please note - for both runs, "correct" is a function within the same module):

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('out.txt','w')

def spelltest():
    for i in test:
        print correct(i)

test = ['acess','accesing','accomodation','acommodation','acomodation',
'acount','adress','adres','addresable','aranged','arrainged',
'arrangeing','aranging','arragment','articals',
'annt','anut','arnt','auxillary','avaible',
'awfall','afful','basicaly','begining',
'benifit','benifits','beetween',
'bicycal','bycicle','bycycle']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print spelltest()
```

This does not:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(r'C:\Python26\out.txt','w')

infile = open('C:\\Python26\\text.txt','r')

def spelltest():
    for line in infile:
        print correct(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print spelltest()
```

Any thoughts on what the issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

One difference is that in the second example, `line` will retain the newline characters (`\n`) from your file. The first example doesn't have those characters.

Also, I assume that `text.txt` is formatted with one word per line.

P.S. To remove the newlines (and other whitespaces):

```
def spelltest():
    for line in infile:
        print correct(line.strip())
```

Comment: Yes, I should've stated that. text.txt is formatted one word per line. I tried reformatting text.txt without newline characters, but this resulted in no output generated within out.txt. Any ideas as to how I can go around this issue if it is in regards to the newline characters? Should it loop through item per item within the list as opposed to line by line?

Comment: I tried it. It only removed the spacing between each line within the output, but did not succeed in "correcting" the text.

Comment: @user1185790: Why don't you include the actual input file in your quesiton, so we don't have to guess?

Comment: ['acess',
'accesing',
'accomodation',
'acommodation',
'acomodation',
'acount',
'adress',
'adres',
'addresable',
'aranged',
'arrainged']

Answer (score 0):

Given your file format, you could manually add "words =" at the beginning, e.g:

```
words = ['acess', 'accesing', 'accomodation', 'acommodation', 'acomodation', 'acount', 'adress', 'adres', 'addresable', 'aranged', 'arrainged']
```

and then save it as text.py instead of text.txt .

Afterwards, you can import the list in your actual script with:

`from text import words`

and no parsing whatsoever  will be needed